# Сравнение нескольких массивов; создание массива, с сортировкой по количеству вхождения элемента в массивы

Tags: php, массивы

Есть несколько n массивов:

```
$arr1 = array(1,10,100);
$arr2 = array(100,200)
$arr3 = array(1,100);
```

Необходимо сравнить массивы, на предмет одинаковых элементов и отсортировать по "весу" значений. Т.е. в данном случае результат магги, хотелось бы видеть таким:

```
array(100,1,10,200)
```

Мое решение включает в себя перебор значений массива, со сравнением других массивов, назначение "веса", путем подсчета повторяемости. Вложенные циклы и не очень красиво.
Возможно ли более лаконичное решение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объедините массивы [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-merge.php), подсчитайте вхождения значений [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-count-values.php), отсортируйте с сохранением ключей по убыванию [`arsort()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.arsort.php), выведите ключи [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-keys.php).

```
$merge = array_merge($arr1, $arr2, $arr3);
$c = array_count_values($merge);
arsort($c);
$result = array_keys($c);
print_r($result);
```